# How to get all Tickets where( the last status == 'string')

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The relationship of the table was Ticket has many status

Ticket Table

Ticket ID

- 1
- 2
- 3

Status Table

ticket_id   -  Status

- 1           -  created
- 2           -  created
- 2           -  working
- 3           -  created
- 3           -  working
- 3           -  finished

I used this code but last() not work.

```
$tickets = Ticket::whereHas('status_table', function ($query) {
      $query->last()->where('status_column', 'working');
})->get();
```

I want to get the ticket/s where the last status is "working" using eloquent or query builder.

base on the table sample:
the result is Ticket ID #2 only

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you can use something like this `$query->where('status_column', 'working')->latest()->first();`

Comment: The Ticket_table hasMany Status_table, so that code not work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure depends on the wording for the order of your status.

like, how do you know that "Finished" is the last status ? DB doesnt know that.

you still can get your result this way:

```
$tickets = Ticket::whereHas('status_table', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status_column', 'working');
})->whereDoesntHave('status_table', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status_column', 'finished');
})->get();
```

Comment: "how do you know that Finished is the last status" this is what i want to get, but i have many status "pending", "sent", "working", "paused", "resumed", and "finished".
Then should I code that whereDoestHave() per status?
Do have more less code. Example I want to get where last status is paused or resumed.

Comment: as i said, your statuses are subjective. and it will lead to messy queries